# How to separate an overgrown blog into sub-blogs – without breaking existing inbound links?

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, migration, directory

I have a single WP install that has accumulated a mix of content, large subjects of which I want to separate into something resembling their own blogs.  Example:

Among the pages and posts on `myblog.com` are large numbers pertaining to `birds`.  But every post on birds is mixed in by publication date with the other posts on `myblog.com`.  I want to:

1. Create a virtual (or should it be a truly separate?) `birds blog` at `myblog.com/birds`, with its own front page.
2. Segregate `birds` content from the other content at `myblog.com`, so that `birds` posts don't show up in the root `myblog.com` post lists, nor do tags or categories for `birds` show up in the root blog's tag clouds or category lists.
3. *But:* inbound links to the old `birds` page and post permalinks still (ultimately) reach them at their new `/birds` subdirectory.

I can see features that produce some but not all of this functionality (e.g., use an archive page and ensure all `birds` posts share the top-level `birds` category; or create a separate WP install and migrate all `birds` pages and content to it...) but I don't want to start down a road only to learn after much hacking that I can't accomplish all three of the objectives above.

Comment: I don't see any real need to overthink that, in my opinion you should focus on how to organize your contents using taxonomies, the built-in _category_ can be enough. From a SEO perspective the side effect is the post permalink may change (not necessarily, it depends on your current permalink structure and how you're currently use - or don't- some kind of archiving for your posts) so it  can be important to properly redirect those links

Comment: This is mostly a server question.

Comment: You may also see if changing posts to custom post type and custom taxonomy serves your objective you trying to achieve, using a plugin like post type changer, you can change all birds posts to custom post type: bird. Then being separate CPT it will have own /birds cpt archive, and also it will not appear in root blog posts which will be picking just posts belonging to default post type called: post